# Embedded C programming style

Tags: c, loops, embedded, firmware

I have noticed a programming style in Embedded C, used for firmware programming:

```
#define WRITE_REGISTER(reg, value) \
        do { \
           write_to_register(reg, value); \
        } while (0)
```

How does this do...while (0) help over:

```
#define WRITE_REGISTER(reg, value) write_to_register(reg, value)
```

Comment: This is the best thread I've found regarding the do-while macro. Hope it helps, not sure if it will. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros

Answer (score 10):

As you can see [here](http://www.rt-embedded.com/blog/archives/macros-in-the-c-programming-language/) the `do {} while(0)` permits to avoid compilation errors or bad working when there are multiple lines in the macro and you try to call the macro in the same way as a c function (which is the way everyone does).

As an example (I report the one in the link here so you don't need to navigate the page)

```
#define DO_SOMETHING_HERE(_x) foo(_x); bar(_x);

if( condition )
    DO_SOMETHING_HERE(_x);
else
    ...
```

will generate a compilation error because it will result in:

```
if( condition )
    foo(_x); bar(_x);;
else
    ...
```

Using the do while everything will work fine, infact it will be:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING_HERE(_x) do{ foo(_x); bar(_x); }while(0) 
if( condition )
   do{ foo(_x); bar(_x); } while(0);
else
   ...
```

Note that in this case putting braces will not save you because:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING_HERE(_x) { foo(_x); bar(_x); } 
if( condition )
   { foo(_x); bar(_x); };
else
  ...
```

still generates an error.

In your case I think it's only a coding style because there's one line only.

Answer (score 1):

With this kind of loop definition, you can use `break` statements within.  This allows easier error handling.  Example:

```
do
{
    /* A lot of code */

    if(error)
        break;

    /* A lot of code */
{
while(0)
```